# openpyxl: assign value or apply format to a range of Excel cells without iteration

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to apply a specific format or assign a value to a range of Excel cells without iterating over each cell. I am currently using this script:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

## With iterations

# Apply style
for i, rowOfCellObjects in enumerate(ws['A1':'C4']):
    for n, cellObj in enumerate(rowOfCellObjects):
        cellObj.fill = Font(name='Times New Roman')

# Assign singular value to all cells
for i, rowOfCellObjects in enumerate(ws['A1':'C4']):
    for n, cellObj in enumerate(rowOfCellObjects):
        cellObj.value = 3

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

But I am looking for a shorter notation, like this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

## Without iterations

# Apply style
ws['A1':'C4'].fill = Font(name='Times New Roman')

# Assign singular value to all cells
ws['A1':'C4'].value = 3

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Does `openpyxl` or another module offers something like this?

*ps: I'm using Python 3.5*

Comment: Why are you enumerating when you're not using the counter?

Comment: @CharlieClark in the example I provided I'm not using the counter, but in my script I need it to iterate over a DataFrame `df` in order to assign each value to the Excel range of cell: `cellObj.value = df.iat[i,n]`

Comment: Well the code should be the minimal example of what you want to do. It's always tricky when you start mixing and matching code.

Comment: I know I am very late on this but maybe someone would be still interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Excel styles **must** be applied to individual cells because this is how the file format works. Because of the way it works, openpyxl does not provide the desired functionality, but it is possible with [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 17):

This is not quite exact. OpenPyxel allows to apply styles to columns and rows:

According to: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

> Styles can also applied to columns and rows but note that this applies
>   only to cells created (in Excel) after the file is closed. If you want
>   to apply styles to entire rows and columns then you must apply the
>   style to each cell yourself. This is a restriction of the file format:

```
col = ws.column_dimensions['A']
col.font = Font(bold=True)
row = ws.row_dimensions[1]
row.font = Font(underline="single")
```

Comment: That's a snippet of documentation, but could someone explain what that means? Is is so that I *can* apply the style to the whole column, but this will only affect values I type in excel after I save the file in python and open in excel?