# Openpyxl: Formatting an entire row or column up to a designated cell - is it doable?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In openpyxl, is there a way to format an entire row or column and have it stop at a certain cell without iterating over each individual cell.

I.e. can I do something similar to calling ws.row_dimensions[0].font = some_font_object, so that it formats the font of the entire row[0], but have it stop at say column F.

I have a function for formatting both entire rows and columns at once and by iterating over each individual cell. Was just wondering if I can set a limit to the first option.

Comment: As the documentation makes clear, cells have to be formatted individually, so just use `ws.iter_rows(max_row=1, max_col=6)`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to format an entire row or column and have it stop at a
> certain cell without iterating over each individual cell ?

I'm not sure if this would be possible in `openpyxl` (read [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37645437/16120011) answer from @[*Charlie Clark*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385133/charlie-clark)).

AFAIK, you need to loop over the cells individually, this way :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Font

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

randomStyle = NamedStyle(
    name="randomStyle",
    font=Font(name="Arial", size=40, bold=True, color="33c481"),
    # (if needed) add here more styles
)
    
ws.append(range(10)) # here we write values in A0:J0

for cell in ws["A0:F0"][0]: # here, we format a specific range
    cell.style = randomStyle

#another variant
#for row in ws.iter_rows(max_row=1, max_col=6):
#    for cell in row:
#        cell.style = randomStyle
    
wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: FWIW creating and binding formatting objects is quite slow so (noticeably so for a lot a of cells), it's best to move the creation outside the loop. Use NamedStyles if you have more than one formatting property.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark, [`NamedStyle`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.styles.named_styles.html) is cool. I updated the answer accordingly.